# knife azure server list returns empty result

Tags: azure, chef, knife

I'm trying to set up CHEF server and workstation on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've followed several guides, and so far I'm able to get it to list the available images, but "knife azure server list" returns an empty result.

AFAIK I've done all that's required.  I've gotten the publishsettings file, the managementCertificate.pem etc.

Here's my knife.rb contents:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "bruce"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/bruce.pem"
validation_client_name   "company-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/company-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://URL/organizations/company"
syntax_check_cache_path  "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/syntaxcache"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
knife[:azure_publish_settings_file] = "#{current_dir}/Enterprise Dev-Test-Microsoft Azure Enterprise-2-20-2017-credentials.publishsettings"
knife[:azure_mgmt_cert] = "~/managementCertificate.pem"
knife[:azure_subscription_id]  = "specific subscription id i want to work with"
```

Any ideas why I'm not getting anything?  There ARE vms in there...
Thanks in advance!